# Copy / Paste in Excel using clipboard

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, clipboard

After copying data from `PDF` using clipboard. I have three chunks of data in `clipboard` and I want to `Paste` each at different locations in `Excel-2007` let's say:

- Data in clipboard `3` should paste in `A1`
- Data in clipboard `2` should paste in `C1`
- Data in clipboard `1` should paste in `E1`

VBA code

```
 ActiveSheet.Paste
```

is not working here, It will only paste the last thing copied.
**Is it possible to handle `Clipboard` using  `Excel VBA` and how?**

[image]

Comment: As far as I can see this question has been asked before and never got an anwer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807122/excel-vba-paste-the-second-item-from-clipboard. Yet, the question to me is how the data got into the clipboard. VBA has variables and objects which can be easily used to store things and copy them. Why don't you make use of those instead?

Comment: as I mentioned that data is copied from PDF file ( 3 or 4 different locations). if I use variable to copy data it will not consider tables.

Comment: [There is software out there to convert PDFs to Excel.](http://www.nuance.com/for-business/imaging-solutions/document-conversion/power-pdf-converter/how-to/convert-pdf-to-excel/index.htm) Yet, you would have to purchase it in order to make use of it. If you don't have any API (to automate this using VBA) to make use of then you'll have to do it manually. Even though the answer provided by @Vityata might not be what you like it is (unfortunately) the correct answer and VBA / Excel by itself cannot handle PDFs the way you want it to.

Comment: I tried using `Application.SendKeys` to no avail. All I could get it to do was open the office clipboard pane. From there on I was unable to cycle through the list. Someone with more knowledge may be able to expand upon that idea.

Comment: Of course its possible to get VBA to access the clipboard,  but not using methods in the VBA object model  -  The user32 and kernel32 API libraries will allow you to do this which VBA can access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to copy some stuff to the clipboard and to paste it from there, using the macro recorder. Seeing the code, my opinion is that the answer of your question is "NO".

Take a look at the code yourself, you will see that the clipboard position is not referenced at all:

```
Sub Makro2()
'
' Makro2 Makro
'

'
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A5").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A3").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("C4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("C6").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("D13:D14").Select
    Range("D14").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("C15").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A17").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("C18").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: You'r right that the "clipboard position is not referenced".tried it myself. I am searching this question on google for months. Did not find anything, but the twist is `VBA` can handle other Applications so in my opinion `VBA` can also handle `Clipboard` as `application` / `object`. I just need a jump start  ;).

Comment: Well, if you need to handle other applications and to copy from them, then probably you may use a list in VBA to save the values and paste from there, without using the clipboard at all. It would work quite as you want it.

Comment: @Vityata The OP can only do (as you suggested) if he/she has an API to reference the "other application". Otherwise, VBA cannot access this application. As far as I can tell, there is only software out there which he/she will have to purchase in order to do so (at least that's the case with PDFs).

Comment: @Ralph, Well, initially I thought that the clipboard is filled out manually. E.g. opening the pdf, ctrl+A and ctrl+C. If this was the case, then I think that with a userform and a button, a list of objects could be filled out. A little more manual work, but still a solution. I have not tried the PowerPDF, but from the video it seems nice.